# WPF Scrollbar XAML Template dont show Headers

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, templates, scrollviewer

I need help with my own listview scrollbarTemplate. I try to apply my own template but when I use it in my listviews I cant see the Headers.
I guess this happens due to overidden template definitions(?) but I'm not sure.

Do I have to define an own template for the header?

Template so far:

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewScrollViewStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListView}">
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle Fill="Transparent"/>                      
                    <Border x:Name="BorderControlTemplate" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="1" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ScrollViewer Focusable="false" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Template="{DynamicResource ScrollViewerControlTemplate1}"> 
                                <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="BorderControlTemplate" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsGrouping" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ScrollViewerControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
    <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}"
                                CanHorizontallyScroll="False" CanVerticallyScroll="False" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="0" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="VerticalScrollBar"
                   Cursor="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                   Minimum="0" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                   Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                   ViewportSize="NaN" Style="{DynamicResource ScrollBarStyle1}"/>              
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="VerticalScrollBarBackground" EndPoint="1,0" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#EE7F00" Offset="0"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="ScrollBarDisabledBackground" Color="Gray"/>

<Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumb" TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <Rectangle Width="10" Height="50" Fill="#EE7F00">
                    <Rectangle.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="50" Color="Transparent" />
                    </Rectangle.Effect>
                </Rectangle>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="HorizontalScrollBarBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#EE7F00" Offset="0"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>

<Style x:Key="ScrollBarStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="false"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                <Grid x:Name="Bg" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <Border Width="1" Background="#EE7F00" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>  
                    <Track x:Name="PART_Track" IsDirectionReversed="true" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}">
                        <Track.Thumb>
                            <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}" Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ScrollChrome.ScrollGlyph="VerticalGripper"/>
                        </Track.Thumb>
                    </Track>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bg" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBarDisabledBackground}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto"/>
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeightKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarHeightKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HorizontalScrollBarBackground}"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                        <Grid x:Name="Bg" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarButtonWidthKey}}"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="0.00001*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition MaxWidth="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.HorizontalScrollBarButtonWidthKey}}"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Column="1" IsEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}">
                                <Track.Thumb>
                                    <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}" Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ScrollChrome.ScrollGlyph="HorizontalGripper"/>
                                </Track.Thumb>
                            </Track>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bg" Value="{StaticResource ScrollBarDisabledBackground}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Style which is bound on my listview:

```
<ListView x:Name="myListView" Grid.Column="0" BorderThickness="0" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ItemInformationTemplate}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Style={StaticResource ListViewScrollViewStyle}
                            ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=preView, Path=SelectedItem.Item}" Height="Auto" Width="399"
                            FontFamily="Segoe UI">
                    <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn x:Name="SampleHeader" Width="399"  Header="Beispiel Header" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding}" HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource StandardGridViewHeaderStyle}"/>
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <StackPanel></StackPanel>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding UsedItem.Number}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>                     
                </ListView>
```

How can I change the code so the Headers will be displayed properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your ScrollViewer's ContentTemplate to include a `GridViewHeaderRowPresenter`. Something like this:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ScrollViewerControlTemplate1" TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
    <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DockPanel Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
            <ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Top" Focusable="false" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
                <GridViewHeaderRowPresenter AllowsColumnReorder="{Binding TemplatedParent.View.AllowsColumnReorder, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{Binding TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ColumnHeaderToolTip="{Binding TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderToolTip, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ColumnHeaderStringFormat="{Binding TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderStringFormat, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ColumnHeaderContextMenu="{Binding TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderContextMenu, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ColumnHeaderTemplate="{Binding TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderTemplate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Columns="{Binding TemplatedParent.View.Columns, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector="{Binding TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="2,0,2,0" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
            </ScrollViewer>
            <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}"
                                    CanHorizontallyScroll="False" CanVerticallyScroll="False" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                    Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Grid.Column="0" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" />
        </DockPanel>
        <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="VerticalScrollBar"
                   Cursor="Arrow" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                   Minimum="0" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                   Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                   ViewportSize="NaN" Style="{DynamicResource ScrollBarStyle1}"/>              
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Yes, I'm probably as surprised as you to find a `ScrollViewer` inside the ControlTemplate of a `ScrollViewer`, but hey, blame Microsoft :P I just extracted the default template with Blend, to see what you were missing.

To customize the looks of the header, use the `HeaderContainerStyle` of the `GridViewColumn`:

```
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn x:Name="SampleHeader" Width="399"  Header="Beispiel Header" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding}" HeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource StandardGridViewHeaderStyle}">
            <GridViewColumn.HeaderContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type GridViewColumnHeader}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                    <!-- -->
                </Style>
            </GridViewColumn.HeaderContainerStyle>
        </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

Comment: Yes thanks it works fine, but how can i set the background from the headerarea to transparent, but when i have no content the header is still visible.

Comment: Try using `HeaderContainerStyle` or `HeaderTemplate` in the `GridViewColumn`, to customize the header looks.

Comment: Glad to read that :) Please mark this as the answer to your question, so others can find it easily

Comment: Yes. if it does not matter i want to ask one more question, how can i check if the ColumnHeader is empty without a Converter only XAML? Than i want to collapse the header. Thanks.

Comment: You could use Triggers... Maybe setting a `DataTrigger` in the `ScrollViewer` ContentTemplate, bound to the `HasItems` property of the `ListView`, so when the property is `False`, you set the `GridViewHeaderRowPresenter`'s `Visibility` to `Collapsed`

Comment: If you want further details, you should create a new question for that.

Comment: Do you know why this Template doesn't work for Horizontal Scrollbars?

Comment: @probird Because it only contains a vertical scrollbar :P It is a simplified template for vertical-only scroll, but can be easily made for both. I'll add the horizontal scroll bar, too.

Comment: Yeah thanks, i have fix it :D scrollviewer templates are evil.. i have implemented the horizontal scrollviewer and now  i have more items in the listview and the thumb position is everytime on the right side :/

Comment: do you know why i cant scroll when the cursor is between the listviewitems ?